# Plot multiple histograms in R with prob=TRUE

Tags: r

I want to plot multiple histograms in R which do not show frequency, but the density instead:

```
A <- rnorm(100)
B <- rnorm(100)
hist1 <- hist(A,prob=TRUE,breaks=30)
hist2 <- hist(B,prob=TRUE,breaks=30) 
plot(hist1, col="red",lty=0, xlim=c(-4,4))
plot(hist2, col="blue", lty=0, xlim=c(-4,4), add=TRUE, main="Example")
lines(density(A))
```

However, my 'prob=TRUE' option apparently doesn't go through when plotting the objects.  Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to give the same result.

Comment: The problem is that (at least at the plot I get), the histograms are not normalized (the y-axis is still showing the frequencies instead of the density).  However, when I plot the histograms directly (that is, not first save them as an object and then call `plot'), the y-axis has the right values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

leave the prob=T out of the hist() command

```
hist1 <- hist(A,breaks=30)
hist2 <- hist(B,freq=F,breaks=30)
```

And put `freq=F` into the plot command.

```
plot(hist1, col="red",lty=0, xlim=c(-4,4),freq=F)
plot(hist2, col="blue", lty=0, xlim=c(-4,4), add=TRUE, main="Example",freq=F)
```